# Ignoring namespace prefix while parsing xml

Tags: cocoa, nsxmlparser

If a xhtml file has namespace prefixes in the document and the namespace for the prefixes is not defined, is it possible to ignore the prefixes and still parse the file when using SAX parser. Is there a way to get rid of the error "The prefix for element is not bound." without defining the namespace for the prefixes while parsing?

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix for the element is not bound; this is an error in the XML. However; you could try to call `[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];`.

Comment: Can you be more specific, how set this parameter in xsl.